# VBA calling function via VBA and ADO

Tags: oracle, vba, plsql, ado

I have a problem with calling my functions on Oracle server via VBA.
When I try calling function without parameters. It´s ok.
But, when I Calling functions with parameter. I get error ([Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle]Invalid parameter type)
Have any idea?
 This is vba code and plsql (I make elementary function for test)

Vba

```
Private Sub test()
Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error


Set Oracon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
mujuser = "xxxx"
mujPWD = "xxxxx"

  strConn = "UID=" & mujuser & ";PWD=" & mujPWD & ";driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
              "SERVER=xx.xxx;"
Oracon.ConnectionString = strConn
Oracon.Open
cmd.ActiveConnection = Oracon
 cmd.CommandText = "el_test"
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("P1", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 256)
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
cmd.Parameters(0).Value = "ahoj1"

cmd.Execute

End Sub
```

And function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EL_TEST 
(
  P1 IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN 'Ahoj';
END EL_TEST;
```

Thanky you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit, I've never tried to execute a function like this through code, but I'm surprise this worked without the parameter because the way you have your function set up.  I think the way you would want to get the value would be:

```
select el_test('ahoj1') from dual;
```

If you made this change from a *function* to a *procedure*, I think it will work the way you expect:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure EL_TEST 
( P1 IN VARCHAR2,
  p2 out varchar2) is
BEGIN
  p2 := 'Ahoj';
END EL_TEST;
```

And then your VBA would look like this:

```
Private Sub test()
  Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
  Dim objErr As ADODB.Error

  Set Oracon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  mujuser = "xxxx"
  mujPWD = "xxxxxx"

  strConn = "UID=" & mujuser & ";PWD=" & mujPWD & _
        ";driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=xxxx-xx"

  Oracon.ConnectionString = strConn
  Oracon.Open

  cmd.ActiveConnection = Oracon
  cmd.CommandText = "el_test"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.NamedParameters = True

  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, "ahoj1")
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 256)

  cmd.Execute

  Dim result As String
  result = cmd.Parameters(1).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Get function return value with OLEDB

I searched high and low for this but finally solved the problem myself.
My solution is in VBScript but I have represented it in the (untested) code below.
The trick is that the **first parameter is the return value**.

```
Private Sub test()
Dim Oracon As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim param0 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim objErr As ADODB.Error

Set Oracon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
mujuser = "xxxx"
mujPWD = "xxxxx"

  strConn = "UID=" & mujuser & ";PWD=" & mujPWD & ";driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
              "SERVER=xx.xxx;"
Oracon.ConnectionString = strConn
Oracon.Open
cmd.ActiveConnection = Oracon
 cmd.CommandText = "el_test"
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set param0 = cmd.CreateParameter("P0", adLongVarChar, adParamReturnValue, 256)
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("P1", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 256)
cmd.Parameters.Append param0
cmd.Parameters.Append param1

cmd.Execute

Dim result As String
result = param0.Value  ' Use the variable you set. Same as cmd.Parameters(1).Value '

End Sub
```