# Oracle stored procedure in excel without VBA/macros

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to execute this below stored procedure in Excel without VBA/macro code and get output. Any idea how to get this?

```
create or replace 
    PROCEDURE  TEST2 (P_OUTCUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

    IS

    V_ABALPH VARCHAR2(30):= 'TRYS';

    BEGIN

    OPEN P_OUTCUR FOR 

    SELECT *  FROM PRODDTA.F0101 where abalph like '%' || V_ABALPH || '%';
    commit;
    end;
```

---

[excel stored proc output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIxQi.png)

Output of stored procedure should display in Excel sheet.

Here are the steps to get output in excel from SQL server.

http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/

In this similar way can I do for Oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA calling function via VBA and ADO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606397/vba-calling-function-via-vba-and-ado)

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in my post and subject line that I do not wish to code in VBA.  I wish to call procedure straight from excel connection properties and  not VBA. by below steps         http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/

Comment: You can't do that without VBA in excel

Comment: I am able to do it with SQL server. Is there no way we can do with Oracle databases too?

Answer (score 0):

Register your DB in ODBC Sources and then use solution from datapigtechnologies.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Oracle OLEDB connecton string.............  `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=BUD;Data Source=HIBUDP1;Extended Properties="   `                            so should I ODBC connection only then?